# XMLReader to XML file using XMLWriter WriteNode - Very Slow for Large XML

Tags: c#, xml, xmlreader, xmlwriter

In C# I use `SqlCommand ExecuteXmlReader()` to call a SQL Server stored procedure which uses 'For XML' to return large (1gb+) complex XML files (multiple hierarchy).

`ExecuteXmlReader()` returns an `XmlReader` which I wish to save to an XML file.  To do this I use an `XmlWriter` to stream the data from the `XMLReader` to the file system.

```
using (XmlReader xmlFromDatabase = xmlReaderFromDatabase)
{
  var settings = new XmlWriterSettings {Encoding = Encoding.UTF8, Indent = true};
  using (XmlWriter outputXmlFileToDisk = XmlWriter.Create(fileDirectory + fileName, settings))
  {
    outputXmlFileToDisk.WriteNode(xmlFromDatabase, false);
  }
}
```

Side note: I can't load the entire XML into memory (`XDocument`) as it is too large.

My problem is that the `WriteNode` is very slow - it is taking hours to write the file. If I kill my application the XML file written on the disc is partially written since the file is being streamed out to node by node.

Is there a better way to save the XML faster from a `XmlReader` than a `XMLWriter WriteNode`?

(I know there is .ReadInnerXml() but this returns a string which is not good for the size of the XML)

After I export the file is need to transform it (I may use Saxon as the .net framework hasn't proved as performant as I'd like) and schema validate it through C#.

Comment: Internally, the XML data is transferred from the SQL Server as stream of characters (though the internal class `SqlStream` and `XmlSqlBinaryReader`). Therefore, you may be able to directly copy the stream into your output stream using a technique like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29672383/streaming-data-from-a-nvarcharmax-column-using-c-sharp (haven't tried, so I don't post this as answer)

Comment: Also, you may want to have a look at the `PrintXmlValuesViaNVarChar` sample which shows hot to use streaming and async support for XML data via `GetTextReader()`: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh556234(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: It is much faster to save using SQL tools than c# tools.  Look at SQLCMD.exe and BCP.exe.  See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162816.aspx

Comment: Is WriteNode slow or pulling data from the server is slow?

Comment: Pulling data from the SQL Server is quite fast, the XMLReader result is ready to use after just a few minutes of executing the ExecuteXmlReader command. Unfortunately the WriteNode when streaming through the XMLReader using the XMLWriter is taking hours. I need to do this in C# rather than using SQL Server tools because of other filer processing required. Is there another approach or am I doing something wrong?? SQL Server --> For XML SQL Query (large XML extract) --> XMLReader --> XMLWriter (using WriteNode).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution, using `XmlReader`/`XMLWriter` seems to be a good approach to take (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647804.aspx) just that the XMLWriter-WriteNode by default validates the XML as it writes. Since we know the XML returned from SQL Server is XML valid and we also XSD validate all XML before sending it we don’t need to have the writer perform the validation as it writes. Passing the Settings object to the `XMLWriter` with `CheckCharacters = false` prevents the redundant validation and outputs the file in just a few minutes as apposed to hours.

```
var settings = new XmlWriterSettings{
            CheckCharacters = false,
            NewLineHandling = NewLineHandling.None,
            Indent = true,
            Encoding = Encoding.UTF8 };

using (var outputXmlFileToDisk = XmlWriter.Create(fileDirectory + fileName, settings))
{
```